# Bash script does not run via Mac OS Launchd

Tags: bash, macos, launchd, macos-catalina

I have the below script running fine when I'm trying it directly through terminal:

```
count=`ls -l /Users/ben/Downloads/*.png 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
echo $count`
```

and it returns the count as 1 which is correct!

but when I'm running it by launchd it always returns zero!

here is my launchd script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" \
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.ben.Cleaner</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/ben/Scripts/clean.sh</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>22</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/AlTest12.err</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/AlTest12.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

any idea why it's not working through launchd? I'm running on Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: Shouldn't `/tmp/AlTest12.err` hold some clue as to why it fails?

Comment: well, nothing there as nothing fails. instead, it's just returning zero (instead of 1). As I said if I run the script from the terminal it works fine!

Comment: what is the character ` doing in the second line? a typo?
it can be related to the default shell. add the shell at the start of your script. (#!/bin/bash, #!/bin/zsh ...)
try to debug variables and return codes to a file from within the script. also use $() instead of `` in the first line of the script. ;)

Comment: So when you run `/bin/sh /Users/ben/Scripts/clean.sh` from the command-line it runs fine and prints '1'.

Comment: @Roadowl, yep that's right

Comment: @AmirH, that's a type in the post!. both bash file and task definition have the deault shell in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the time interval to the following structure:

```
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>1800</integer>
```

This part:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>22</integer>
  </dict>
```

Didn't work for me, convert everything to seconds, perhaps this may help, it did in my case.